# AWS How to change instance type in template at application migration service and fix it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration

I faced with some strange bug in AWS Application migration service. It successully replicated my VM then I decide to change some parameters in template. For example I usully change type of disks from io1 to gp2 and some network settings as well as I usually want to change type of instace from c4.large to t3.medium for example. After this I save new configuration and make it default. But when I start to create new test instance its create new version of template configuration and all parameters tranfered there well except type of instance. So it is always return back type of instance. If it possible to change type of instance in template and fix these change somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
**General launch settings** - **Instance type right sizing** -> None!